# Hard trajectory of equilateral triangle system

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, analytic-geometry

I was doing this problem in physics class,
[image: Problem Statement]

Time is easy to solve for, using the velocity of approach and dividing the initial separation by it.

Otherwise, I am interested in the trajectory of these particles.

In order to solve for the trajectories, I tried to make use of the unit vectors along the sides but the resulting equations have moduli in them which I don't know how to integrate.
To try a different track, I wondered if it would be fruitful to try a complex number approach.
Is there a way to do this using vectors or complex numbers(Or otherwise)?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please understand that a sufficient knowledge of polar coordinates is necessary to understand this solution and even then this is quite a rough calculation for one particle. Hope this helps.